# CSS overflowing / going beyond container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Please see picture attached, makes it easier to explain what I mean.

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap. I have a page with a col-md-4 and col-md-8. The col-md-4 has the list of countries as seen.

I'm facing two problems.

1. Why aren't my country labels 'wrapping' as soon as they hit the col-md-4 width? (you can see the vertical border) I just want them to flow to the next line without going across

[image]

2. Even when I artificially 'break' the labels after every X occurrences, I see this weird last label of a row breaking up and appearing on the next row (for e.g. see Cape Verde on the bottom of the picture)

Additional details:

Each of the country labels is basically a span

```
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-md-4">
    ...some other bootstrap tabs/panel stuff
    <div>
        <span class="mm-place" id="AU">Australia</span>
        <span class="mm-place" id="CA">Canada</span>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the mm-place class is defined below.

```
.mm-place {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

FIXED: Just used display:inline-block in the mm-place style, and replaced spans with div.

Comment: Wrapping to the next line is how it's supposed to work - this is just text with a border, so if you think about writing out a paragraph of text it's going to move something to the next line whenever a word is too long, not a group of words

Comment: I fixed it. All I needed to do was replace the <span> with <div> and style mm-place with display: inline-block;

Comment: `display:inline-block` would have been enough. You also need to make sure the parent doesn't have `white-space:nowrap`. If it does, set it to `normal` or `initial`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent the text from being split across multiple lines

Updated CSS:

```
.mm-place {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;  //added this
}
```

[**Bootply example here**](http://www.bootply.com/U8GNUiM901)

Note that if any of the country names are larger than the `col-md-4` on their own then the text for that line will be larger than the `col-md-4`.  You can see info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431970/bootstrap-3-truncate-long-text-inside-rows-of-a-table-in-a-responsive-way) for managing overflow text if it applies for you.

Comment: Dan, my main issue is why the span labels are going beyond from col-md-4. In my image, if you see the first line of countries, I expected "italy" to come in row 2 after "India", except that what I see is all the countries are horizontal in one row. I can't seem to get them to stay contained within the col-md-4. What am I missing? PS - I'm editing to show a new image