# text overflow control with CSS/Bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried using `word-wrap` as well as adding a class to `td` to do `text-overflow: elipsis` but nothing seems to be affecting this particular table and I end up with this:

[image]

Here's my HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Family Checks: no placed instances, >1MB size, misnamed</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-fixed" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
                        <thead>
                        <th class="col-xs-1 text-center">
                        #
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-xs-7"><a href="" ng-click="vm.sortType = 'name'; vm.sortReverse = !vm.sortReverse">
                        Name
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'name' && !vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'name' && vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        </a></th>
                        <th class="col-xs-1 text-center"><a href="" ng-click="vm.sortType = 'instances'; vm.sortReverse = !vm.sortReverse">
                        Qty.
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'instances' && !vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'instances' && vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        </a></th>
                        <th class="col-xs-1 text-center"><a href="" ng-click="vm.sortType = 'sizeValue'; vm.sortReverse = !vm.sortReverse">
                        Size
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'sizeValue' && !vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'sizeValue' && vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        </a></th>
                        <th class="col-xs-2 text-center"><a href="" ng-click="vm.sortType = 'elementId'; vm.sortReverse = !vm.sortReverse">
                        Element Id
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'elementId' && !vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="vm.sortType == 'elementId' && vm.sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        </a></th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="i in vm.AllFamilies | orderBy: vm.sortType : vm.sortReverse">
                                <td class="col-xs-1 text-center">{{$index}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-7 text-left">{{i.name}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-1 text-center">{{i.instances}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-1 text-center">{{i.size}}</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2 text-center">{{i.elementId}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
.table-fixed{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .table-fixed tbody{
        height: 500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width:100%;
    }

    .table-fixed thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
        display: block;
    }

    .table-fixed tbody td{
        float: left;
    }

    /*Header*/
    .table-fixed thead tr th {
        float: left;
        background-color: #00b3ee;
        border-color: #00b3ee;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;`, `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, and `white-space: nowrap;` to `td`.

Comment: Your suggestion works. I tried text-overflow: ellipsis on its own before and got nothing. thanks for pointing out the white space nowrap setting.

Comment: Well you seem to have accepted this answer, even though it's more code, but that's fine. Could you at least please check my fiddle and try my answer to see if it works?

Comment: I accepted it because it works. Yours didn't for my case. I don't want to constrain table width like you suggested in your answer.

Comment: The table width I have in the fiddle is just an example. It's not even required. Take it out and the word break still works just fine. This is exactly the reason this property exists.

Answer (score 3):

There's a CSS property for breaking long words. Give that a shot.

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Here's a link from w3 schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

Here is a fiddle I put together demonstrating the use of this in a td element:

https://jsfiddle.net/rhpumk0d/

Comment: I tried adding either, both to the CSS and it does nothing. I am not sure if it's a CSS conflict in how my classes are setup. Where would you put them? Also, as you can see in my code, I am already using word-wrap and it doesn't work.

Comment: You are using word-wrap, my code says word-BREAK :) Have a look at the w3 example I provided. It works there.

Answer (score 1):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` only works when the text parent element has a declared width.

Try adding a fixed width to the *td* element and see how things work out.

Answer (score 0):

Add class text to td/th and fill text in span.

```
.table-fixed td.text span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 truncate long text inside rows of a table in a responsive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431970/bootstrap-3-truncate-long-text-inside-rows-of-a-table-in-a-responsive-way)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for saying obvious, but did you clean browser´s cache after changes? Sometimes css´s styles doesn´t change as far as it still use the cache definitions...

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

or

```
word-break:break-all;
```

should be work

[Clean mozilla cache](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)

[Clean Chrome cache](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)