# In Bootstrap 3.3.7 .table-responsive, is there a way to constrain the width of just one cell and truncating only the text within?

Tags: html, css

I have a complex table which is working nicely on mobile with Bootstrap 3.3.7 .table-responsive, however, I am getting a scroll at laptop screen size and need to truncate only the contents of *one* cell in the table to remedy this. I plan to use a tooltip to allow the user to see any truncated in formation.

I have tried the answers on the following pages to no avail:

[How to work with ellipsis in bootstrap responsive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148127/how-to-work-with-ellipsis-in-bootstrap-responsive-table/39149634#39149634)

[How to work with ellipsis in bootstrap responsive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148127/how-to-work-with-ellipsis-in-bootstrap-responsive-table)

[text overflow control with CSS/Bootstrap table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078841/text-overflow-control-with-css-bootstrap-table)

[Bootstrap 3 truncate long text inside rows of a table in a responsive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431970/bootstrap-3-truncate-long-text-inside-rows-of-a-table-in-a-responsive-way)

I also have tried using a fixed table but this is not ideal for the amount of data I have in the table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed-xs">
        <thead>
            <tr ng-if="...">
                <th class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <label class="i-checks m-b-none">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="..." /><i></i>
                    </label>
                </th>
                <tr>
                    <th class="header text-center">...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center">...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center">...Will contain long text...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center">...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center">...</th>
                    <th class="header text-center">...</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <label class="i-checks m-b-none">
                        <input type="checkbox"/><i></i>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td align="center">...</td>
                <td align="center">...</td>
                <td align="center">...Cell With really really long text...</td>
                <td align="center">...</td>
                <td align="center" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">...</td>
                <td align="center" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">...</td>
                <td align="center">...</td>
                <td align="center">...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

I expect the `<td>` with "Cell With really really long text" to be the ONLY one containing truncated text (ideally in the middle as the text will be an email address).

I am utilizing Bootstrap 3.3.7 and can not convert to 4 at this time. I do understand that this has been a reoccurring issue with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Bootstrap works in a 12 column system. Just add the number of columns to your class... https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child() in your class to reached the td where you want to give the specific width, and rest of the div take width automatically as they are currently have.

```
Suggested css code

table>thead>tr>td:nth-child(2){
  width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it didn't for me. Ended up that we had a js controller blocking a lot of flex.